# Convert Phone format to 111-111-1111

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I have an input text field, I need to convert the number what ever entered to this format `111-111-1111`.

```
var regex = /^\(?[0-9]{3}(\-|\)) ?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/; // using this to match
```

Don't know how to convert to the specific format which I need

Comment: `num.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');`

Comment: Or, `mum.replace(/\D+/g, '').replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4}).*/, '$1-$2-$3')`

Comment: [Demo Regex Update](https://regex101.com/r/iT8XGO/2)

Comment: how  can i substring out to get and set it to this 111-111-1111 format

Comment: its not working for (111) 111-1111 or (111)111-1111

Comment: Did you try my approach? It seems working. `console.log(" (111) 111-1111 ".replace(/\D+/g, '').replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4}).*/, '$1-$2-$3'));`

Comment: if the format is (234) 567-8911 and what should i change in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove all non-digits with `replace(/\D+/g, '')` first, and then take the first 10 digits, format and discard all the rest with `replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4}).*/, '$1-$2-$3')`:

```js
var s = " (111) 111-1111 ";
var res = s.replace(/\D+/g, '').replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4}).*/, '$1-$2-$3');
console.log(res);
```

The main regex details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{3})` - Group 1 capturing 3 digits
- `(\d{3})` - Group 2 capturing 3 digits
- `(\d{4})` - Group 3 capturing 4 digits
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars

The group contents are placed back into the resulting string with the backreferences (`$1`, `$2` and `$3`).

EDIT: To obtain the `(111) 111-1111` format, use

```js
var s = "111111111-1111 ";
var res = s.replace(/\D+/g, '').replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4}).*/, '($1) $2-$3');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: if i need a output format like (111) 111-1111 format and input will any? how should i change the above code.